# manipulate elements in a list - c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings of the following pattern: "name\middleName".
What is the nicest way to turn into a list in which all the elements are just "name"?
(i.e split the string and leave only the "name" part)

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> originalList = ...
List<string> newList = originalList.Select(s => s.Split('\\')[0]).ToList()
```

Comment: You probably meant `[0]` to get the `name` portion.

Comment: should actually be element [0], but +1 for a good solution.
Edit: Ahmad beat me to it. :)

Comment: Oh ya, for some reason i was thinking the name was after the `\\`. Fixed now

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> original = ...
List<string> nameOnly = original.ConvertAll(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('\\')));
```

If it's possible that there might not be a `\` character in some elements of the original list then you'll need an additional check to avoid exceptions:

```
List<string> nameOnly = original.ConvertAll(s => {
                                                     int i = s.IndexOf('\\');
                                                     return (i == -1) 
                                                         ? s
                                                         : s.Substring(0, i);
                                                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//your list of strings in format (name\middleName)
List<string> list;
List<string> newList;

foreach(string item in list)
   newList.Add(item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("\\")));
```

That would make a copy of your string  list into a new one formatted like you wanted.

Comment: don't think you can change the items in a foreach like that.

Comment: @Eric I had changed it to adding to a new list before you posted this.

Comment: things happen fast with new questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize "/" and assign the first string to name variable.
Or just make loop of all those strings in a list and inside a loop do a loop on a string length which puts chars into variable and exits when reaches "/" and then stores it as a name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular expression solution for you that doesn't create a new list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
{
     list[i] = Regex.Match(List[i],@"^\w+").value      
}
```